# Getting 404 for share link on Facebook debugger although it shows all the meta tags

Tags: facebook, metadata, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I am debugging the below link:

> https://www.alldaydr.com/product_detail/EllaOne/Nw%253D%253D%250A/

on facebook's share debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/.
I can see all the meta-tags scrapped by facebook and no errors or warnings still it shows 404 in the preview card.
[Screenshot](https://imageresize.org/view/8220ff70-9153-4815-885a-a2f355beb213)

Comment: _“still it shows 404”_ … because that’s what your system responded with, for that particular request. Up to you to go figure out, why! Maybe you have plugins installed that try to block requests by bots that way, something like that.

Comment: @CBroe It's working for all the social sites, (Twitter, Linkedin, google+, slack too) also I verified it using curl command and it doesn't respond with 404 `curl -X HEAD -I https://www.alldaydr.com/product_detail/EllaOne/Nw%253D%253D%250A/`

Comment: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=dns%3awww.alldaydr.com&run=toolpage reports IPs from a totally different range, than the one the Facebook debugger shows. And a local ping from my machine gives a totally different one as well.

Comment: Re-scraping it right now resulted in an IP from the same range I see locally, and in that case no 404 error. So something with your DNS setup might not be quite right.

Comment: I'll verify and share the response, Thanks @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

There is some redirection happening, it goes to https://www.alldaydr.com/home. That page is missing a doctype, and the Open Graph URL is wrong:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="asdas">
```

Without the redirection, there are still 2 problematic things:

- No doctype.
- A lot of code before the Open Graph tags. You need to put metatags first.

There can also be some server configuration sending a 404 to Facebook, of course. That´s more likely the case right now.

Comment: Yes, it is redirecting but it is due to the below javaScript which i have kept if(!/bot|googlebot|crawler|spider|robot|crawling/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { document.location.replace(pathname) } , the redirection will only happen if you visit the site via browser. So how can it redirect the facebook bot to the home page?  The redirection is purely by JavaScript. Also, the tags are working perfectly for generating Twitter, slack, Google+ cards.  Thanks, @luschn

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help! Following your solution, I have added the doctype and put the metatags first, still, I am facing the same issue i.e. all the metatags appear in facebook debugger but shows 404 in the preview card.

Comment: quick suggestion: use a correct og image. the specification says 1200x630 pixels.

Comment: Added a placeholder image with the exact size, still not working, need to find some other way  https://www.alldaydr.com/1200x630.png

Comment: in that case, i would go with CBroes comment. your server seems be the issue.